# How are days visited figured?

Tags: support

Every day I make a point of going on all of the Stack sites I'm subscribed to so that I can get the badges for consecutive days.

Today they were all okay, except for the Tex site that has reset from 18 days back to 1.

I know I've been on it in the last 24 hours and the others all updated, so my question is why would that one be different?

Comment: Perhaps start here: [Why did my consecutive days disappear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55394/168244)

Comment: @Werner Okay, I guess I have to do more on each one than just visit the page. Thanks.